# Android. ScrollView doesn't scroll first time, but then when content changed it does

Tags: android, xml, android-scrollview

I have my views in a scroll view so that if the content is bigger than the screen size, the user can scroll down. I have noticed a weird thing.

The first time the content comes up, it doesn't scroll. However, when the user changes a setting and the content of the views which are inside the scroll view reloads it does become scrollable.

Why is this? Is it clear what I mean?

EDIT: This only happens on my Nexus 5X. But when I used a Samsung J10 it works right away.

My XML is a relative layout, with a child element of the scroll view, which contains other views.

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_home"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.apps.reuven.egertandcohentravel.Activities.HomeActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_home">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    >




    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewLinkToOrder"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Click here to book travel insurance."
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:gravity="center"

            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttons_linear_layout"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@id/textViewLinkToOrder">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/choose_country_button"
                android:onClick="onChooseCountryButtonClick"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Choose country"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#ffff"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/textViewLinkToOrder"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>


            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/automatic_country_button"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="My Location"
                android:layout_below="@id/choose_country_button"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>




        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutAllDetails"
            android:layout_below="@id/buttons_linear_layout"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="No country yet selected"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/textView_coumtry_name"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/police"/>

                <TextView
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Police"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/police_text_view"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/police_phone_button"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/sym_action_call"


                    />




            </LinearLayout>



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ambulance"/>

                <TextView
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Ambulance"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/ambulance_text_view"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/sym_action_call"
                    android:id="@+id/ambulance_phone_button"


                    />




            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/israel_consulate"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:textSize="17sp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Israel Consulate"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:textSize="17sp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/israel_consulate_text_view"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>



                </LinearLayout>



                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/sym_action_call"
                    android:id="@+id/israel_phone_button"

                    />




            </LinearLayout>




            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/chabad"/>



                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:textSize="17sp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Beit Chabad"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:textSize="17sp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/chabad_address_text_view"
                        android:text="3 Blue Street, USA"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:textSize="17sp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/chabad_number_text_view"
                        android:text="+44 456 3245234"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>



                </LinearLayout>


                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/sym_action_call"
                    android:id="@+id/chabad_phone_button"


                    />




            </LinearLayout>





        </LinearLayout>







    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Thanks very much, I can't figure this one out.

Comment: I suspect there are a lot of memory/cpu pressure.  A lot of weight calculation and nested view layers. You can try systrace to profile.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem and by adding a TableLayout inside ScrollView solved the problem for me. Then, add your content (RelativeLayout) inside TableLayout.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="1">

        <-- Your RelativeLayout goes here -->

    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Let me know if that solved the problem. Do not forget to add the attribute fillViewport=true to ScrollView so the TableLayout match it's parent's view width and height.

Comment: This didn't change anything. Didn't work. But Thanks

Comment: @Μιχάλης Θεο for you it worked because you have `android:fillViewport="true"`